# VBA Interop: Is there a way to Explicitly use Excel data types in a word macro and vise versa?

Tags: excel, vba, types, ms-word, dynamic-typing

I'm reading data from an excel spreadsheet in a word macro so I can use the spreadsheet to instantiate a document from a template and set properties in the instantiated document from the excel table.   I'm trying to be as explicit with types as I can, but it turns out that the object that comes back from an excel selection has rows typed differently than a row in a word document.  Not actually that surprising now that I think about it.  Is there a common base class more specific than Object between an excel spreadsheet row type and a word table row type?  Maybe a way to specify that excel row type?  Or is my best bet to use the Object type and not worry about the details.  Dynamic typing is amazing here, most of the class methods are the same.

I am also interested in running word based VBA subroutines (located in normal) from excel VBA.  I tried to look it up via Google but did not have any luck.

The guts are here:

```
 Set testList = LoadExcel(strFile)
 testList.Activate

 Dim allSuites As Object 
 ' LoadExcel also selects the rows that contains the data we want in excel
 Set allSuites = testList.sheets("FullSuiteList").Application.Selection

 Dim myRow As row
 Dim Columns() As String

    Dim i As Integer

    ' Previously I used a table in word, but there are too many columns 
    '     to be manageable
    ' LoadPropertyNames testList.Tables(1).Rows(1), Columns
    ' For i = 2 To testList.Tables(1).Rows.Count


    ' Now we get data directly from our Excel sheet 
    LoadPropertyNames allSuites.Rows(1), Columns

    For i = 2 To allSuites.Rows.Count
        CreateOne allSuites.Rows(i), Columns
   Next I

   ' row type yields type mismatch at runtime.  myrow as Object works though.
   Function LoadPropertyNames(myRow As row, Columns() As String) 
   ...
   End Function

   ' row type yields type mismatch at runtime.  myrow as Object works though.
   Function CreateOne(myRow As row, Columns() As String)        
   ...
   End Function
```

Comment: Looking at the similar questions, VBA is not well received here, interesting.

Comment: In the VBA editor, in the Tools menu choose References then add "Microsoft Excel ##.# Object Library" to your Word VBA project. This will give you access to all of Excel's objects. Note that some object names, e.g. "Range" represent different objects in Word vs Excel, so declare variables as Word.Range or Excel.Range as appropriate.

Comment: @xidgel Oh, that's super easy, damn.  That is exactly what I needed, turn that into an answer, and I'll put the elementary tag on this question.

Comment: Ah, 7 days later and I totally understand that this question is not ready for prime time.  I was stuck in forum mindset, but the light is dawning.  It looks like there is no worthy question about Word <---> Excel macro interoperability doesn't exist.  I'm not ready to commit to the effort now, but I hope to be back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the VBA editor, in the Tools menu choose References then add "Microsoft Excel ##.# Object Library" to your Word VBA project. This will give you access to all of Excel's objects. Note that some object names, e.g. "Range" represent different objects in Word vs Excel, so declare variables as Word.Range or Excel.Range as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks!  There's no similarly easy way to access subroutines in word's normal.dotm from excel, is there?

Comment: Yes there is. I'll post it in another answer to make it easier to read than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the comment about running one of the Normal template's subroutines. First in Excel add a reference to the the Word object model --- in the Tools menu choose References then add "Microsoft Word ##.# Object Library" to your Excel project. Then here's an example of how to call a Normal template sub:

```
Sub RunNormalTemplateSub()
    Dim wdapp As Word.Application
    Dim wddoc As Word.Document

    Set wdapp = New Word.Application
    wdapp.Visible = True

    ' This is the line that runs the sub
    ' This runs a sub named "ThisIsATest"
    ' in the module "Sandbox"
    ' in the Project/Template "Normal"
    wdapp.Run "Normal.Sandbox.ThisIsATest"

    ' If the sub takes arguments then you would call
    ' wdapp.Run "Normal.Sandbox.ThisIsATest", Arg1, Arg2


    Set wdapp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note that **Word** is running the subroutine. I don't know of a way to have Excel run the Word subroutine (maybe it can be done, but I don't know how).

Hope that helps

Comment: This is also good stuff.  I've been dabbling in VBA for so long, but easy stuff like this still surprises me.  How is the VBA area over on documentation beta?  By the way, I think it's good that word runs it.  It would involve some gymnastics on Microsoft's part to get the object models of word vs excel to iron out properly for the foreign VBA code.